# Chart math values 0-100% from a series of items

Tags: recreational-mathematics, percentages

I have data $$a=12988, b=77, c=923, d=6494$$ for example

Trying to build a chart that represents a $0-100\%$ value but relative to the highest (a).

What calculations would I need to get this to plot correctly? (a) would be $100\%$ then (d) would be $50\%$ because it is half of (a). (b) would be a small percent but you can see it on the chart not so small it cant be seen. (linear)?

My output would be something like this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:100%;" data-name="a"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:2%;" data-name="b"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:30%;" data-name="c"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:50%;" data-name="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to confirm I understand the question, are you asking how to calculate the answer to questions like "what percentage of 12988 is 923?"

Comment: no, just a relative percentage based on the highest value I think. It has been years since I did this stuff and cant remember. I think it would be like from 12988 if that was 100% then what would be the percent values of the b,c,d based on the highest value in this case 12988

Comment: Once you know that 12988 is the highest value, "the percent value of c" is exactly the answer to "what percentage of 12988 is 923?". If you're asking how to code this in a particular programming language like Javascript, that's no longer a math question and not appropriate for this site.